# Unable to parse manifest.json. ionic v3 --livereload ios device

Tags: ios, json, ionic3, manifest

Running my ionic app on ios device with --livereload enabled.  I get the following error when closing the app and restarting it:

```
Unable to parse manifest.json. Ensure the file is valid JSON     ionic-pro.module.min.js
```

This is my current environment:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim    : 6.1.2 
    Node       : v8.9.3
    npm        : 5.6.0 
    OS         : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.iecis.sp.portal" version="0.5.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>My App</name>
    <description>An Ionic App</description>
    <author email="ionic@ionic.io" href="https://ionicframework.com">Ionic Team</author>
    <content original-src="index.html" src="http://192.168.2.94:8100" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <hook src="hooks/after_build/010_copy_browser_to_docs.js" type="after_build" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="file://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="500" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <platform name="android">
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.2.94:8101" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.2.94:8100" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^6.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="^2.1.1">
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="<android_api_key>" />
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="<ios_api_key>" />
        <variable name="LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION" value="Show your location on the map" />
        <variable name="LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Trace your location on the map" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="com-sarriaroman-photoviewer" spec="^1.1.11" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="^2.2.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic" spec="^3.0.0">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="<app_id>" />
        <variable name="CHANNEL_NAME" value="Master" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_API" value="https://api.ionicjs.com" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_METHOD" value="background" />
        <variable name="MAX_STORE" value="2" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-mode" spec="^0.7.2" />
</widget>
```

Ionic Cordova Plugins:

```
com-sarriaroman-photoviewer 1.1.11 "PhotoViewer"
com.googlemaps.ios 2.5.0 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 1.7.1 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.2 "BackgroundMode"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.1.1 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 2.0.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic 3.0.0 "IonicCordova"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.1 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.2.5 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
```

Two questions:

1. Why am I getting this error?
2. Where do I start debugging?

Any help/advice/nudge would be greatly appreciated.  Let me know if you need more information.

UPDATE:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Ionic",
  "short_name": "Ionic",
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "assets/imgs/logo.png",
    "sizes": "512x512",
    "type": "image/png"
  }],
  "background_color": "#4e8ef7",
  "theme_color": "#4e8ef7"
}
```

Comment: Your error is in your manifest.json file, so show us this file...

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, only on Android though. I have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What fixed this error for me was to remove and re-add the ios platform, with:

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Answer (score 3):

i have fixed the issue.
install the plugin:
`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save`
and update the `config.xml`:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*"/>
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

you can follow [this guide](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/) from ionic docs:

Answer (score 0):

Things to try

- on your index.html
- could also be that the file is malformed, save it again in UTF8 encoding, put it through JSON validator.
- Did you actually replace the APP_ID with your app id.

in node_modules/@ionic/pro/dist/ionic-pro.module.js

change

```
var path = 'manifest.json';
```

to

```
var path = './manifest.json';
```

Comment: 3 json validators all say that it is correct.  I re-saved with UTF-8 encoding.

I don't have the app_id in here, is that an issue?

I changed the path and will report back shortly.

Comment: nope that did not work, trying reinstall of the platform AGAIN

Comment: The path change will work but this won't work when the build is via ionic's online service. I've pulled my hair out too with this issue, couldn't find any permanent solution either.

Comment: @JoelDavey Whenever an Ionic Pro Deploy update occurs on my Samsung Galaxy S6 (Android 7.0) device I get this manifest.json parsing error after the update has downloaded, extracted, and then the app is redirected. No errors on iOS 11 devices, though.

dependencies:
"@ionic/pro": "^1.0.20",
"cordova-android": "6.4.0",
"cordova-ios": "4.5.4",

devDependencies:
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9",